# Removing SurfaceView from the application stack

Tags: android

Hello StackOverflow Users,

I am new to android and trying to develop a game in which I use a

1) Main class to redirect (like a menu.. new game, options, help, exit etc..)

2) A surfaceview class

3) A thread to handle drawing on canvas.

I have added an exit button on the main class.

However after playing the game i.e. drawing the objects and using them, when i redirect to my Main class and try to exit; the main screen disappears but the view and threads aren't destroyed.

This is the main class.

```
package com.tgm.welcome;

import com.tgm.R;
import com.tgm.main.GThread;
import com.tgm.main.TGMActivity;
import com.tgm.options.OptionsMain;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Welcome_Act extends Activity {

    ImageView game, exit, options;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        game = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newGame);
        options = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.options);
        exit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exit);


        game.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                gotogame();
            }
        });

        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            goto_opt(); 

            }
        });


        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                exit_game();
            }
        });
    }



    public void gotogame() {
        Intent game = new Intent(Welcome_Act.this, TGMActivity.class);
        startActivity(game);
    }

    public void goto_opt() {
        Intent opt = new Intent(Welcome_Act.this, OptionsMain.class);
        startActivity(opt);
    }

    public void exit_game() {

        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

PLEASE HELP TO REMOVE THE GAMESCREEN FROM THE STACK THAT ANDROID MAINTAINS.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call **finish** on the activity you want to remove from the stack.. it does the work you want..

Answer (score 1):

Using System.exit(0) is not advised in android. It doesnt guarantee finishing the Activity.

Instead of

```
public void exit_game() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Use:

```
public void exit_game() {    
    Welcome_Act.finish();
}
```